# How to use office365 mail from Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, ms-exchange, office365

When I setup my account in Thunderbird - with all the correct server settings - the connections gets refused, saying the username/password do not match.

Is there any special setting you need to have?

Answer (score 0):

For connecting Thunderbird with your office365 mail account  ...

1. you don't need your mail password, that you set up (past form verb)
2. you **need your *application password***.

Requirements:

Two-factor identification setup

Detailed explanation by Microsoft: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-app-password-for-Office-365-3e7c860f-bda4-4441-a618-b53953ee1183

Rough explanation: Get `app password`, if you already logged into your mail account ever in your life:

- Log in per web interface
- Settings → Account settings → Security and privacy → Additional security verification → Update my phone numbers used for account security → follow screen